# Trying to play music through AVPlayer in a uitableview, but the wrong music is being played (wrong music is being loaded from Firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, avplayer

So I have a UITableViewController, and inside each cell is a play button and a pause button in order to play music. When you press the play button, it should play the music specific to that cell, however when I run my code, it plays random audio, not the one I specifically loaded for it. Also when I scroll through the tableview, the audio stops playing. Why is this the case and how do I fix it? I also want it to switch songs if the play button in a different cell is pressed.

Here is the function that I use to load the unique string (produced by `post.mp3`) to find the url file into my AVPlayer:

```
func loadAudio(post: CompPost, completion: @escaping (URL) -> ())
    {
        let audioRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("cPosts").child(post.uid).child("Audio").child(post.mp3)
        audioRef.downloadURL
        { (url, error) in
            print("mp3filename: " + post.mp3)
            guard error == nil else
            {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return /**alert**/
            }
            self.audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(url: url!))
            completion(url!)
        }
    }
```

Here is the code that loads the unique url for each cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cPostCell", for: indexPath) as! cPostCell
            
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.index = indexPath
        
        //other code omitted for brevity

        loadAudio(post: compPosts[indexPath.row])
        { (url) in
            print("THIS IS THE URL")
            print(url)
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

function for hitting the play button:

```
func playMusic(index: Int)
    {
        audioPlayer.play()
        isPlaying = true
        print("playing now")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not loading new `AVPlayerItem` into your `AVPlayer` when you trigger `audioPlayer.play()` Therefore when you hit play button, player starts to play the Item that was loaded in your last loaded `tableViewCell` . Try saving all playerItems into array with some index , and when user taps the button with index you load the audio and within loading you assign new `AVPlayerItem` into `AVPlayer` :

```
 audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: yourPlayerItemArray[index]))
```

and after that you trigger `audioPlayer.play()`

Comment: This concept worked. I got an error when clicking the play button for the same cell twice, so I just made an array of URLS. Good news, it's not a random song playing anymore, bad news, it's not the correct song playing, the array is shuffled. Any ideas?

Comment: Adding on, the array is in a different order every time, but each cell still plays the song it's assigned to. :/

Comment: @EAO123 It is in different order, because playerCells are resused, try saving items not by appending to array, but inserting to array position  that is your cellIndexpath.row, or use dictionary where your cellIndexpath.row matches key in dictionary, for example dictionary like this:  [Int: AVPlayerItem]

Comment: I tried that and it gave error. I just updated the way I save data to my database, instead of the audio filename, i did the audio url so i didn't have to deal with asynchronous bs, and it worked.

Comment: @EAO123 I am glad to hear it finally worked!